# what is the best way to know if an insert statement violate the unique contraint in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

in my android application my plan is to run a bunch of insert statements using `SQLiteDatabas` object.

What I want is when the insert statement violates the unique constraint such that I could know in what insert statement the error happens and that insert statement doesn't affect the `DB`.

Does any one know how to do that? I saw `insertWithOnConflict` and `insertOrThrow` method. Can I know form the first method when a unique constraint violation occured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is when the insert statement violates the unique constraint such that I could know in what insert statement the error happens and that insert statement doesn't affect the DB.

If the `INSERT` statement violates the unique constraint, it will not affect the database, by definition. It will throw a `SQLiteException`. If you need to know specifically which `INSERT` violates the constraint, execute them one at a time, wrapped in your own transaction (`beginTransaction()`, `setTransactionSuccessful()`, `endTransaction()`).